# 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null when trying to assign role to existing user Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to assign role to existing user but I'm getting this error.

**My User Controller:**

```
 public function show(User $user) {
    return view('admin.users.profile', [
        'user' => $user,
        'roles' => Role::all(), 
    ]);

  public function attach(User $user) {
  $user->roles()->attach(request('role'));
  return back();
  }
```

**My form:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('user.role.attach', $user)}}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <input type="hidden" name="role" value="{{$role->id}}">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Attach</button>
                </form>
```

**I am getting this error in browser:**

```
insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (2, ?)
```

So I suppose that I'm not returning user_id, only role_id by clicking on button for attaching..

Comment: It looks like route model binding makes some trouble :) Can you share your route file?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't bind `user` in your route. It need to be something like:

```php
Route::put('/users/{user}/attach', [App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 
'attach'])->name('user.role.attach');
```

You can of course modify a little bit your route but most important thing here is that you expect User in controller but you didn't bind in route ;)

Comment: Thanks! This helped and solved the problem!